# Поиск определенного слова в тексте с помощью метода substring

Tags: javascript

Что значит `if (hits1.length)`? То есть, чему равняется эта длина?

```
var text = "Walla walla Wee Gillis salt and pepper Wee Gillis peas and carrots Wee Gillis walla walla Wee Gillis salt and pepper Wee Gillis peas and carrots";
var myName = "Wee Gillis";

var hits1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === myName[0]) {
    if (text.substring(i, i + myName.length) === myName) {
      hits1.push(i);
    }

    console.log("\nsubstring\n");
    if (hits1.length) {
      for (i = 0; i < hits1.length; i++) {
        console.log(hits1[i], text.substring(hits1[i], hits1[i] + myName.length));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В JavaScript, следующие значение преобразуются к `false` в инструкции `if`:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `+0` и `-0`
- `NaN`
- `""`

Все остальные значение преобразуются к `true`. (Смотрите спецификацию, [пункт 9.2](http://es5.javascript.ru/x9.html#x9.2))

В данном случае, если `hits1.length` равно `0`, то код внутри блока `if` не выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

`hits1` - это массив, его длина равна числу положенных в него элементов. `hits1.push(i)` кладет в него число i, если найдено совпадение в `text` со строкой `myName`. Проверка `if (hits1.length)` расшифровывается как `if ((bool)hits1.length)`, при этом (bool) возвращает ложь, если ему передали пустоту или 0, и истину в остальных случаях. Соответственно, если эта длина оказывается нулем (т.е. совпадений не найдено), список совпадений не пытается выводиться, если не ноль, выполняется цикл по массиву.

P.S.: проверьте балансировку скобок {} в коде, их здесь немного не хватает.